# Image upload & gallery

Tags: 7, entities, files, media

Is there a way to limit the number of imagefield fields present in a node?
I am using [iTweak Upload](http://drupal.org/project/itweak_upload), which allows to upload an unlimited number of images, but I need something that can limit the number of uploads.

I want to make a gallery per node with the uploaded files; what module do you recommend?

Comment: Are you interested on still using _iTweak Upload_, or are you interested in using a different module?

Answer (score 1):

If you use standard CCK imagefield, you can set the number of images that can be uploaded within one field. For example, you could allow just one image, or up to 10 images, or an unlimited number of images.

Providing you don't have hundreds of images per node, CCK imagefield is fine for having a gallery of images on each node, and we've implemented galleries quite successfully in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at my CCK Gallery module - http://drupal.org/project/cck_gallery - for some ideas. It's out of date now, and should probably be a Feature - there is no intention to resurrect it, but it might be a good starting point.

I don't really understand "limit the number of imagefield fields" - I mean, you can limit the number of permitted uploads on a field already, so I guess that's *not* what you mean, but I can't work out what you do mean.